# Java how overwrite Exception.getMessage

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, overriding

I have problem in `exception.getMessage()` method when raised for `NullPointerException` which returns null.
How can I overwrite base `Exception.getMessage()` to control it without changing in JRE?

Comment: Create your own `CustomException` by extending `Exception` class and then override the `getMessage()` in it.

Comment: Dear friends, Thanks, In my app I use some libraries (jar) and I am writing a general error log. I have noticed one of libs method throws NullPointerException an when I want to log it in my system ,I get null from getMessage(). The problem is If I extend base Exception class, other Exception classes can't inherited from my new one. I think if I can override (overwrite) base Exception class and modify getMessage method, I can handle generally in all Exceptin clases raises.
how can I change base Execption class and already inherited classes affected also. something like modifying core source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public MyException(Throwable throwable) {
        super(throwable);
    }

    public MyException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
        super(message, throwable);
    }
}
```

Throw MyException one program.

```
try {

} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    throw new MyException("My exception message", e);
    or
    throw new MyException("My exception message");
    or
    throw new MyException(e);
}
```

Catch MyException another program.

```
try {

} catch (MyException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Since `NullPointerException` extends `RuntimeException` this doesn't work in some cases

Comment: Yes, just as example, Better to extend Throwable or RuntimeException

Answer (score 1):

As `nullPointerException.getMessage()` returns `null`, there is now message passed to its constructor.
Since you could create your own `Exception` (but I can't understand **why**), you may also generate `NullPointerException` with text message:

```
if (something == null) {
  // here you may want to log another data
  throw new NullPointerException("mandatory value 'something' is NULL");
}
```

Note that both ways assume that you are able to change source. If `NullPointerException` is generated somewhere in standard class(f.e. in the `HashMap`), you need investigate **why** this happens by debugger and/or reading sources for that class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are designing your method to throw out the NullPointerException, you may construct a NullPointerException object in the throw clause

for example your method name is nullPointer。

```
public void nullPointer() throws NullPointerException{
    do something;
    throw new NullPointerException("I am a new null pointer exception");
}
```

if your code generates such exception per se unexpectedly, you need to check your code's logic to prevent from such exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you print out "" message for stack trace always?

Comment: Nope, you can enter whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the constructor method of [`Exception.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Exception.java)

```
public Exception(String message) {
    super(message);
}
```

everything you need to do is just add your error message when you throw the **exception**.

or if you want to customize your exception class extends the `Exception.java`, please add the corresponding constructor like:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```